# How to fix broken internal DNS in Rancher 1.6

Tags: docker, rancher, dnsmasq

Everything was working fine in Rancher and services could ping / discover each other. Then I added a dnsmasq service which was supposed to be the dns and dhcp server for my home network. This seems to have broken the Rancher internal DNS though, as services can no longer ping / discover each other, even on the same stack. I have removed the dnsmasq service from Rancher to no avail. I'm using Rancher 1.6. Ideas anyone ? Thanks

Comment: Did you try restarting the nodes?

Comment: Yep restarted multiple times - both nodes and the cluster

Comment: Can you please collect logs using: https://github.com/rancher/rancher-logs-collector and share them with me? You can find me on https://slack.rancher.io.

Comment: Also if you can share any relevant logs here, it would be helpful to debug.

Comment: The logs that you shared with me are incomplete due to the failed setup. Couple of things that I can see are you are using Calico which is not supported by Rancher. You need to use CATTLE_AGENT_IP if you are using the same host to run both rancher/server and the agent.